# Run ./gradlew bundleRelease doesnt generate release aab in react-native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to publish my app to playstore. I've read on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android to run ./gradlew bundleRelease. I followed all the instruction, but after I run ./gradlew bundleRelease and it said "Build Successfull", I don't have my bundle release till now. please some advice.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Configure project :app 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-dialog-progress 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Configure project :react-native-image-crop-picker 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Task :realm:forwardDebugPort 
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
adb: error: no devices/emulators found
===========================================================================
WARNING: Failed to automatically forward port 8083.
In order to use Realm in Chrome debugging mode, port 8083 must be forwarded
from localhost to the device or emulator being used to run the application.
You may need to add the appropriate flags to the command that failed:
    adb forward tcp:8083 tcp:8083
===========================================================================



BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2m 29s
```

Comment: do you meant you cannot locate your `.aab` file?

Comment: @kenmistry yes... but in documentation it said "The generated AAB can be found under  android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab", and I cant found it,

Comment: perhaps it is in another directory under `build`. do a search based on `.aab` file type extension and see if it pops up.